# Can I have an otherwise High Medieval society, if they are in perpetual Bronze Age?

Tags: technology, medieval, alternate-history, metals

I may have been too ambitious with one property of my advanced Mesoamerican civilisation. The very summarised background (which you can take as given; don't frame challenge this) is that after a wise king in Teotihuacan invented a writing system that was usable by the general populace, and started sailing the Caribbean for guano, both the population and its literacy rate boomed. Over time bureaucratic realms replaced tribute empires, and by the 13th century Mesoamerica had become a second China on the world stage; a developed society of a hundred million people. Contact with Europe was eventually established but because this time plagues went in both directions, and the Mesoamericans were better equipped to fight any invaders, both continents survived with their societies largely intact.

Here's the thing: I want to maintain a number of changes from Europe, and probably the most consequential one is probably the continued lack of iron. My Mesoamericans can have copper and gold, for jewels and currency, and a bit of bronze is possible for specialised use (there was some tin in Mexico); but no iron except for the few trinkets they traded from people in the Pacific Northwest.

So what does the absence of iron and steel entail? For many applications of iron there are alternatives: woodworking joints instead of nails, a [macuahuitl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macuahuitl) instead of a sword, bronze for precise tools. [This page](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/1warvr/eli5how_exactly_does_iron_beat_bronze/cf08emd/) even suggests that bronze is not that much softer than iron but just easier to produce because you only need the one kind of ore. The absence of steel might be more consequential, but right now I cannot think of a place where you *really* need the hardness of steel in the middle ages; except in blades, and blades only need to be super-hard in order to not be broken by other blades or on hardened armour. If nobody has steel, then that arms race doesn't exist, to my understanding at least.

What else does the lack of iron entail? Cannons are going to be hard but this society can do without gunpowder entirely. Having to use wooden/stone/bronze ploughshares would make agriculture a bit more inconvenient, but not debilitatingly so, I hope.

So I am looking for **the most radical and consequential changes that a lack of iron would effect on an otherwise High Medieval society**. I hope they are not too debilitating, preventing a China-like state from even existing.

---

Specifically, the China/Europe-in-the-year-1250-like properties I want are:

- High population
- High degree of urbanisation
- Bureaucratic government
- Enough food surplus to allow for expenses on sciences, arts, a standing army, etc.

Note that I'm not asking for any specific Inventions like clockwork, printing press, etc, unless any of those happen to be crucial for any of the above items. I really want a subcontinent as developed as 1250s Europe, with expansive private commercial enterprises, with many different cities and places where people could pursue arts and sciences. And preferably with a bureaucratic government rather than a hereditary one.

Does a lack of iron stand in the way of any of those? If so, to what degree, and are there creative ways around it?

Comment: Hi AlexP. You are going to comment that High Middle Ages as a term does not apply to Song Dynasty China, and that the two were very different cultures in the 1250s and so on. I don't care; aesthetically my empire would have properties of both; but organisationally speaking closer to China.

Comment: Can you tell specifically what you need from 1250 AD China, which you can't get in, let's say, 1 AD China?

Comment: @Alexander Really the items in the bullet points. I don't think 1 AD China would have printing for example. There's also that 1250s China had much higher population and thus more room for arts and philosophy, and it was much more bureaucratic and less of a warlord state.

Comment: you didn't specifically mention printing press. And this is something that can be done without iron or steel.

Comment: @Alexander It was just one of the examples of the kinds of technological and artistic advancements you can get by having a sizeable portion of your populace living in safe cities instead of on farms. I'm not specifically asking for printing press, only for a society that could invent the printing press among other things.

Comment: If your question is "How can we get a sophisticated city-based civilization with little or no iron", this had been successfully solved in European antiquity (and in China and other places too). If you have specific issues with certain inventions, please list them so we can look.

Comment: @Alexander Do you not perceive any difference between antiquity and the high middle ages, except that the latter had a few more Inventions?

Comment: Well, you mentioned yourself that this difference does not really require iron or steel. I generally agree with you here, but need this list of "fancy gadgets" that you want to have to be sure. Four bullet points that you mentioned definitely do not require iron/steel.

Comment: @Alexander And as I said, I am not asking for any specific gadgets. This question is not about engineering a clockwork or something specific: it is about a society with ten times the population of any culture in antiquity, allowing people *en masse* the freedom to pursue creative endeavours. You still had many serfs in the 13th century but society as a whole was much more developed, people had breathing room so to speak, to collect ludicrous amount of wealth without even being directly involved with the government, and craft art on a scale previously unimaginable.

Comment: @Alexander The whole reason why antiquity did not survive the fall of Rome is that the only people largely able to live a Roman lifestyle were the people living in Rome and a few other cities. The Mongol Invasion on the other hand never ended the tech at the time, even if it had been more successful and taken over Europe, because everything everywhere was more developed.

Comment: I want to know if I can have such large-scale continental development without iron or steel.

Comment: Is it absolutely essential that other cultures possess iron, or can this  be dealt with as a planetary engineering issue?

Comment: @Draft85 It's Mesoamerica, and there are no other civilisations like it in my version of the Americas, so there are no cultures in contact with my Mesoamericans that possess iron in great amounts - until they make contact with Europe, which is outside the scope of the question. So you can say that as far as the empire knows, lack of iron is a planetary condition.

Comment: I've added the tag to make it clear it's still Earth per-se. Please feel free to revert if I've gotten the wrong end of it.

Comment: @Draft85 To be honest I don't know what that tag really signifies. Every question set on earth would technically qualify. But it won't do any harm.

Comment: It seems to be distinguished from the [tag:alternate-Earth], which refers to human development where the planet is significantly different - which might allow for too low a concentration of O2, or no iron deposits,something like that.

Comment: The hardness and wear resistance of steel comes to a lot of things, plows, scythes, shovels, hammers, picks, chisels, saws, axes, you know the common everyday tools that civilization is built on.

Comment: Worth noting one of the biggest disadvantages the Aztec had was not having an animal that could pull a plow.

Comment: Cannons made out of bronze were for a long, long time superior to those made of iron both in handling (didn't rust, were lighter) and safety (less prone to bursting). Iron had only one big advantage over bronze and that was that it was cheaper. Handguns would be a problem since bronze doesn't scale down well, but artillery cannons would not be an issue. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's not forget, there are other alternative tech trees to explore as well, even in a society without iron (or metal, for that matter)- some of which the Mesoamericans did already have a head-start in IOTL. Remember, the world’s first natural plastics were discovered and used by them, after all; and incorporated into tools, weapons and for other purposes. Long before the Europeans arrived, they ‘discovered’ rubber, just as the Austronesians were the first to 'discover' gutta-percha- a rigid, naturally biologically inert, resilient, electrically nonconductive, thermoplastic latex produced from the sap of the tree- and introduced it into the Western world in a more processed form. And whilst the *Palaquium gutta* trees which gutta-percha's extracted from are exclusively native to the Sundaland bioregion, there is actually a native American equivalent, which is even more abundant and cheaper. *Manilkara bidentata* (aka  Bulletwood, Balatá, Ausubo or Massaranduba), is a species of *Manilkara* native to a large area of northern South America, Central America (incl. the entirety of Mesoamerica) and the Caribbean. And the natural, bio-plastic latex extracted from it is near-identical to gutta-percha (aka as *gutta-balatá*)- but was never extracted or utilized by the native Americans prior to European settlement IOTL. In your timeline though, you could easily change that.

So, even in the absence of iron and steel, there are many alternative solutions which full mastery over both bio-plastics would offer (e.g, gutta-balatá horseshoes, weapon staffs/handles, utensils etc) along with opening up other potential applications which iron and steel never could. For instance, if they can have copper as well, then gutta-balatá cables offer them the potential to manufacture/craft insulated electrical wires long before anyone else. Along with other benefits of effectively bypassing the Iron Age, and hopping straight into an organic Plastic Age instead- like far superior plumbing and sewage pipes (with the improved hygiene and reduced disease providing a great boon), doors and window frames, pneumatic tires, better shoes to march with for your soldiers, etc. And if you're looking for those 'China/Europe-in-the-year-1250-like properties' (a high population, high degree of urbanisation, bureaucratic government, and large enough food surplus to allow for expenses on sciences, arts, a standing army and the like) without iron or steel, then having the Mesoamericans discover gutta-balatá as well as rubber, whilst fully utilizing the both to their maximum potential, would probably be the most realistic and plausible solution, as well as a fairly creative and culturally distinctive way around it. What do you reckon?

Comment: I am intrigued by this answer :) An alternate tech tree is precisely what makes for the best worldbuilding, I just hadn't considered plastics! Horseshoes are a funny idea given that America did not have horses, but there are definitely interesting things to consider here.

Answer (score 5):

The absence of iron and steel, from one perspective, mostly just makes other endeavors more expensive.

For example, with a bronze (instead of steel) tire on your chariot or wagon wheels, your folks must replace tires (and wheels) more often. The society needs a percentage more wheelwrights, and correspondingly more lumbermen to sell them wood, more miners to sell them bronze, and more farmers to sell all those new folks food.

Looked at another way, it might cost 7 [ningis](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Ningi) to replace a tire every three months...but an 18-ningi steel tire would last a whole year.

If a merchant is paying that wagon to haul sea-otter pelts from California, the cost of that job is higher for bronze tires than for steel. The cost of those pelts at market will be a bit higher to cover those costs.

Of course, it's not just tires. It's plows and barrels and cookware and llama-shoes (no horses) and tools and weapons and sailing rigging and so much more. The emperor and subordinate governors need more folks toiling (a bit less efficiently) to fill the royal treasury and pay for empire-expanding efforts.

However, steel isn't everything. The Emperor can find offsetting efficiencies. The Bourbon kings of France and the Incas both had some clever organizational ideas on how to keep the peasants hard at work. The Dutch and English figured out how to harness banking and debt-based finance to decentralize economic decision-making (and raise enormous sums to win wars). The Portuguese leveraged secret navigational data into a wealthy empire. You can certainly make your Americans sophisticated and advanced.

Comment: you don't need more farmers to get better technology you need less farmers, you need farming that is productive enough you can feed a lot of non-farmers. If growing a bushel of wheat costs more there is less to go around.

Comment: @John sure, some places the answer will be A, some places the answer will be B. Improving efficiency of food production, among many other possible non-technological improvements, was intended to be implied by the final paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

**Before I answer your question...**

You've asked two questions. In the title, you ask how to have a perpetual Bronze Age. In the body text, you ask if the lack of iron in one hemisphere would, for lack of a better brief statement, upset the status quo.

Those are *very, very* different questions. You might want to update your title.

**Now, on to the question.**

You have some cool pros and cons that would make a good story.

**Some Cons:**

- Plows. Europe can take greater advantage of agriculture than Mesoamerica.
- Shovels/Picks. Construction benefits from iron, as would irrigation.
- Horseshoes. Do not underestimate the value of horseshoes.
- Canon....

**Some Pros:**

- Europeans in Mesoamerica would have only a momentary advantage. Ammunition depletes, iron rusts, tools break... and there's little to no opportunity to repair or replace.
- The Iraq/Iran war in the 90s proved that a technologically superior force can be pressed and overcome by shear numbers.
- Metal was common during the high middle ages - but not at any level resembling what we see today. Quality varied considerably. We're talking the equivalent of Europe 1,000-1,250 A.D. If I recall correctly, few soldiers wore significant metal armor. While all would have knives, many were armed with halberds, spears, and pikes. Expeditionary forces were likely better armed and armored, but I believe it would be a mistake to think of combat in terms of the old Civilization III tanks-vs-spearmen concept.
- Which leads me to skill. If you think about it, our historical perspective is that the unarmed but skilled warrior is far more terrifying than an armored warrior of almost any skill. Bronze weapons are certainly weaker than iron/steel weapons ... but a bronze weapon in the hand of a skilled warrior is superior to almost any weapon in the hands of a lesser-skilled combatant.

**Conclusion**

On the Mesoamerican home turf, iron would not provide a dramatic advantage. It's overcome by sheer numbers.

On European soil, iron is more of a problem  — but it's not a guarantee of success. Trained warriors are not to be trifled with, and one can assume that a Mesoamerican expeditionary force would represent a high skill set as we can assume the same for a European force.

When it comes down to it, you don't want any answer to give you a definitive pro or con answer. You want the variables, because you can obviously write your story with the outcome you want. What you need are the strengths and weaknesses so you can develop an interesting and believable story. I hope that's what I've given you.

Comment: "Europeans in Mesoamerica would have only a momentary advantage" - long enough for Hernán Cortés and Francisco Pizarro to succeed.

Comment: @Alexander We're not talking about the Mesoamerica Cortez visited. We're talking about a High Middle Ages and very well organized Mesoamerica. Coretz found, by comparison, completely disorganized tribes with nowhere near the industrial capability that the OP's Mesoamerica would have. But your point is well taken.

Comment: @JBH I would hardly called the Aztec disorganized tribes. Also the Aztec had copper tools just like the OP's proposal.

Comment: If a soldier is wearing armor chances are they are skilled, armor is expensive. Also skill is a double edged sword, being very skilled can hamper when the techniques you learned no longer work, techniques honed against unarmored opponents are not good against poeple in steel chainmail, helmets, and breastplates. even in Eurasia people with iron had a huge advantage over those without.

Comment: That's not how I expected the title to be interpreted, but alright. @John Organised around Tenochtitlan and its sister cities in a tributary relationship. The relations were built on benefit to the city, rather than mutual benefit. That's why it collapsed so easily, because nobody besides the people of Tenochtitlan wanted to remain Aztec.

Comment: @KeizerHarm that could describe most empires, including all the little empires all over Europe, conguest was a fairly common practice. .

Comment: @John Toulouse was not a tributary of France, they were the vassal. The essence of feudalism is that it's a reciprocal relationship: generally the stronger party offers military protection and the weaker pays taxes. A tributary relationship is one-sided: the weaker party pays taxes to not be assaulted by the stronger party. Sometimes they do it anyway. A tributary empire is held in place solely by the military might of the city on top. That's why they are relatively easy to topple; everyone under them is patiently waiting for a chance to break free. Which they did when Cortez arrived.

Comment: @KeizerHarm and again that describes a lot of Europe. And they were not "patiently waiting", rebellion happened and was suppressed, again just like much of Europe. Pay taxes or have your rebellion quelled is basically how empires work.

Comment: @John I take it you are a Libertarian? Your description of "basically how empires work" works only for both the HRE and the Aztec Empire in the sense that it works for any kind of government. It is way too generalised to appreciate the difference in internal dynamics and resulting stability between political entities on either side of the Atlantic.

Comment: @KeizerHarm feel free to explain how the differences are relevant but the idea that many cities and territories would not rebel given the opportunity ignores most of European history. Also no I am not a libertarian, nice dismissive generalization. The only reason we take note of technologically inferior enemies prevailing is because it is incredibly rare.